# What is the component for if-clause in digital logic?

Tags: vhdl, digital-logic

Do you have any ideas which component use for if clause in digital logic
What is the component for if-clause in digital logic?

Comment: Your question is unclear. In what context and for what types and what conditions?  VHDL has no predefined external block statements used for component instantiation (see IEEE Std 1076-2008 3. Design entities and configurations, 3.1 General). Those would be provided by users or by vendor libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The answer they are looking for is probably *multiplexer*.

Answer (score 0):

In VHDL:
Your if-statement will be synthesized by a synthesizer who decides what to do with it. Mostly, if-statements are synthesized by generating a multiplexer. But keep in mind, that your synthesis tool might synthesize your if-statement to a more optimised structure of gates, that does not neccessarily resemble to a classical multiplexer.

You can try to synthesize your code and have a look at the RTL-schematic.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, most of the time, the chained if-else structure will be synthesized to simple and/or/... gates.